# iPhone app programming: best element from the interface builder to display calculated values

Tags: ios, iphone, interface, label, builder

I apologize if this been asked before, I've searched but havent found the answer I'm looking for.

I'm writing an app that will calculate various values and display that value in the interface use. One example is the days until a various event. What would be that best element from the interface builder to display this information? Use Labels and update the labels to display the values? Any help would be greatly appreciated, and again I apologize if this has been asked before. If it has and I was unable to find it please point me in the proper direction.

Answer (score 2):

`UILabel` is good for short pieces of text (which can include numbers like "45.3450004" etc.).

Answer (score 0):

UILabel will be good. OR

You can use Text Field with User Interaction Disabled.